# How do the componets of a gui work in linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, desktop, gui

there are at least a few basic components:

```
-server (to talk to drivers and listen for input)
-desktop environment (?)
-windows manager (manages apps boarders, size, position, etc) 
-other polishing apps (menus, clocks, icons)
```

So what keeps track of where the mouse is and other interactive activity?

what would happen if some of these components went missing say i ran Firefox without a windows manager or desktop enviroment would it run full screen with out mouse?

how do i completely start and stop a gui from terminal?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The mouse cursor is managed by the graphics server – clients receive input events, but do not need to draw the pointer on their own.

So are the windows, too – the general 'multiple windows' concept is part of the core X11 protocol, so you can still run apps in X11 without a window manager, but they'll be borderless and you won't be able to move or resize them. The default "no WM" focus mode is focus-follows-mouse.

(In Wayland, the window manager is the same process as the graphics server. Additionally in most Wayland environments (and even some X11 environments like GNOME 3), window decorations are typically drawn by clients themselves, so the lines kinda blur.)

---

"Desktop environment" isn't a component. It describes a *collection* of components – among other things a DE includes:

- a window manager & some shell UI (e.g. desktop, panels, and stuff) – this may be a single process as in GNOME 3 or e17, or entirely separate from each other as in Xfce;
- perhaps a settings manager (like gnome-settings-daemon) for various tasks like power settings or display hotplug;
- and a session manager to actually launch everything – this is the 'initial' process that's started by a DM or startx, and killing it results in a hard logout.

Additionally, DEs also have a set of basic apps – file manager, terminal, text editor, system settings; things you'd see in Windows under "Accessories".

---

There are two ways of starting the graphics server – through a display manager, or manually.

Common display managers are GDM, LightDM, SDDM, KDM, Xdm – their main task is to automatically detect when a graphics server (i.e. a display) can be started, and usually to show a graphical login prompt as well. The display manager itself is a system service managed via `service` or `systemctl`.

The manual approach is to run `startx`, which launches Xorg plus whatever clients were listed in the `.xinitrc` file (which could be a DE's session manager, or a plain old WM).

(Xorg can be started completely manually but won't do anything useful; since it takes over the screen, you'd have to start the initial clients from elsewhere.)

Comment: ok so in my own words and please correct me if im wrong!

1.display manager:
(LightDM, GDM and xdm) says when graphics server can start and when login can start.
startx (a manual version of a display manager (this is why the xinit process exists seperatly so both display manager and startx can work with the same settings))
2.graphics server:
(xorg , Wayland(with WM)) draws graphics for gpu driver, handles muse input cursor, keyboard, etc
3.windows manager:
(openbox, fluxbox) draw boarders and manager for location/size of apps

Comment: oh and thanks ton i feel like i much better understand this now!

Comment: Pretty much right. (Most actual "drawing" is done by programs themselves or by their toolkits like gtk/qt – so the graphics server's job is to put everything together into one screen and pass it to the driver.)